# Android NDK + Eclipse: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, eclipse, android-ndk, freetype2

I'm trying to use Freetype with Android NDK + Eclipse, but I got an error when I include this in my project:

```
#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H
```

Error message:

> fatal error: ft2build.h: No such file or directory

Here is the Android.mk in jni/freetype2:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := freetype
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := freetype/lib/libfreetype.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/freetype/include/freetype2 $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Here is the project's Android.mk (in jni folder):

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := CNSD_CPP
...
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -landroid -lGLESv2 -lEGL -llog
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := freetype android_native_app_glue
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
$(call import-module,android/native_app_glue)
```

And I have that header file in the dir:

```
jni/freetype2/freetype/include/freetype2
```

and when I CTRL+Click on it, the Eclipse shows me the file. What am I doing wrong?

---

@Alex: I ran ndk-build V=1 and the end of the result is this:

> [armeabi] Compile++ thumb: CNSD_CPP <= Log.cpp
>   d:/Development/Android/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -MMD -MP -MF D:/Development/Projects/workspace/CNSD_CPP//obj/local/armeabi/objs/CNSD_CPP/Log
>   .o.d -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector
>   -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -mthumb -Os -g -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing
>   -finline-limit=64 -Id:/Development/Android/android-ndk-r9c/sources/android/native_app_glue
>   -Id:/Development/Android/android-ndk-r9c/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/include
>   -Id:/Development/Android/android-ndk-r9c/sources /cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/armeabi/include
>   -Id:/Development/Android/android-ndk-r9c/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/include/backward
>   -ID:/Development/Projects/workspace/CNSD_CPP//jni -DANDROID  -Wa,--noexecstack -Wf ormat -Werror=format-security    -std=c++11  -Id:/Development/Android/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-15/arch-arm/usr/include
>   -c  D:/Development/Projects/workspace/CNSD_CPP//jni/Log.cpp -o D:/Development/Projects/workspa
>   ce/CNSD_CPP//obj/local/armeabi/objs/CNSD_CPP/Log.o [armeabi] Compile++
>   thumb: CNSD_CPP <= Main.cpp
>   d:/Development/Android/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -MMD -MP -MF D:/Development/Projects/workspace/CNSD_CPP//obj/local/armeabi/objs/CNSD_CPP/Mai
>   n.o.d -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector
>   -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -mthumb -Os -g -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing  -finline-limit=64 -Id:/Development/Android/android-ndk-r9c/sources/android/native_app_glue
>   -Id:/Development/Android/android-ndk-r9c/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/include
>   -Id:/Development/Android/android-ndk-r9c/source s/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/armeabi/include
>   -Id:/Development/Android/android-ndk-r9c/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/include/backward
>   -ID:/Development/Projects/workspace/CNSD_CPP//jni -DANDROID  -Wa,--noexecstack -W format -Werror=format-security    -std=c++11  -Id:/Development/Android/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-15/arch-arm/usr/include
>   -c  D:/Development/Projects/workspace/CNSD_CPP//jni/Main.cpp -o D:/Development/Projects/works
>   pace/CNSD_CPP//obj/local/armeabi/objs/CNSD_CPP/Main.o
>   D:/Development/Projects/workspace/CNSD_CPP//jni/Main.cpp:3:22: fatal
>   error: ft2build.h: No such file or directory  #include 
>                         ^ compilation terminated. make.exe: *** [D:/Development/Projects/workspace/CNSD_CPP//obj/local/armeabi/objs/CNSD_CPP/Main.o]
>   Error 1

Comment: Try to tun `ndk-build V=1` from command line, and post the log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use cygwin shell to build with NDK toolchain. Open normal Windows command line, and use `ndk-build.cmd` instead. Make sure that all paths are specified in so-called mixed format, e.g

```
d:/Development/Projects/workspace/CNSD_CPP
```

Update: now I see that

```
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/freespace2/Android.mk
```

is missing. It should be placed after `BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY` and before `include-module`.

Comment: I refreshed my question according to your answer. The error is the same. Btw, my Android.mk files are okay? Didn't I forget something out from them?

Comment: Yes, I missed that include. :) Thanks! Now I have differenet error: libfreetype.a: member at n is not an ELF object. I read that I should check my archive file with .../arm-linux-androideabi-nm if it is valid android ar file, but it says "File format not recognized" in every .o file in it. Of course it is another problem, your answer is accepted. :) I guess I have to figure out the right configure to cross-compile freetype for android.